# Add a field to output feature of a geoprocessing tool?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy, polygon, spatial-analyst, watershed

I am running the Watershed tool and RasterToPolygon tool in a loop for a number of points:

```
flowdir = "flow.tif"
flowacc = "flowacc.tif" 
pnts = [arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x=0.0, y=0.0, ID = 12)), arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x=1.0, y=1.0, ID = 15))] #Create some test points
out = []

for i, p in enumerate(pnts):

    out.append("C:/temp/wspoly_%i.shp"% i)  #Create the output filename
    snap_pt = sa.SnapPourPoint(p, flowacc, tolerance = 100) # snap the point 
    ws = sa.Watershed(flowdir, snap_pt) # calculate watershed raster
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(ws, out[i]) # convert watershed raster to polygon
```

Ideally, I'd like the output to have an ID field taken from the ID attribute of each point.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: arcpy.addfield_Management ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you just have to add those two lines in your "for" statement:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(out[i], "Point_ID", "LONG")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(out[i], "Point_ID", str(p.ID))
```